# Adding MySql.Data reference in Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Tags: c#

When I add a reference to `MySql.Data` and run my code, I get this error:

> Warning   1
>   The primary reference "MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5".   WindowsFormsApplication1

Is it the version of MySql connector? Or is it the file version of MySql.Data? What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: I gotta tell ya- it's probably because you're using an outdated framework. Update it to at least Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Can you upgrade the target version of the project to 4.5.2?

Comment: In our school we also use same version of Visual Studio, actually I get a copy of the software from school. When using it in school it works, but in my laptop it isn't working and shows that error.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya what do you mean I need to upgrade the what??

Comment: The MySqL.Data you are using is targeting to .net framework 4.5.2 and your project is targeting 4.5 that's why you are seeing this error. If you change the target framework of your project to 4.5.2 the error will be gone.

Comment: So I need to look for MySql.Data.dll that targets .net framework 4.5? If there's nothing wrong with MySql.Data then what is it that I need to change? The .net framework?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to upgrade the project to target at least .NET 4.5.2. If you're using VS2013, you'll need to install the appropriate targeting pack (see here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637).

Once you've installed the targeting pack, open up your project, right click on the project file (in the solution explorer) and click Properties, then select .NET Framework 4.5.2 as the target for the project.

Comment: I downloaded and run it but in the end of extraction it only shows "An error was encountered" "Unspecified error"